# What transformation preserves first term and averages the opposite conjugates?

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, convolution, cross-correlation

I can't figure not find any reference on what is this transformation (what $X$ represents in relation to $A$).

If $A=[a_1+jb_1, a_2+jb_2, a_3+jb_3, ..., a_n+jb_n]$, $X$ is defined as:$$X=\left[j b_1, \frac{(a_2 - a_n) + j(b_2 - b_{n})}{2}, \frac{(a_3 - a_{n-1}) + j(b_3 - b_{n-1})}{2}, ...\right]$$

---

That is, given $A$, $X = [j\cdot\text{Im}(A(1)), 0.5\cdot(\ A(2{:}N) - \text{conj}(A(N{:}2))\ )]$. Is this some sort of correlation or convolution?

It should be meaningful for calculating $\text{ifft}(X)$, but I can't see how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this some sort of correlation or convolution?

No. For that you'd need to build products from the elements. You only do differences.

> It should be meaningful for calculating ifft(X), but I can't see how...

I'm not immediately recognizing these terms, and the length of 5 seems very odd¹; so, this is probably an algorithmic step in a specific FFT algorithm of a specific length (probably something with radix-5?), so can't tell you what it's used for.

Notice that differences of reversed-order elements is what you find in the Butterflies of the Cooley-Tukey algorithm. So, maybe looking through that helps clarify this for you.

---

¹ pun fully, utterly and ultimatively very intended.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight, Marcus! Yes, the expression for order 5 must be an algorithmic step in a specific FFT algorithm of a specific length. I've adjusted the expression accordingly for a discrete signal of length N.

Comment: yep, the hint with the Butterflies still stands.